# Trouble installing BeautifulSoup4 (Windows 10, python 2.7, visual studio pro 2013)

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, installation, importerror

I'm new here and am a novice programmer. I'm trying to put together a basic web scraper with python as a project for myself while I continue to learn programming and get more practice.

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup 4, and have followed instructions for installing it from multiple sources. I have installed and reinstalled BeautifulSoup 4 using pip, easy_install and setup.py multiple times, and no matter what I do, the bs4 module is never recognized. I'm not sure where else to go with this, as my hours of google searching is coming up with no other alternatives.

I have Python 2.7 installed, and I use Visual Studio 2013 professional with python tools. I have also attempted to access the bs4 module in IDLE to no avail. If I move the bs4 folder to my python project root, it will work, however I feel as though that shouldn't be necessary.

I have been using the following line to access the bs4 module:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I always get the following output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "I:\PythonProjects\bs4_install_test\bs4_install_test\bs4_install_test.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ImportError: No module named bs4

EDIT: I am confident I only have a single version of Python installed (2.7) and have verified that 2.7 is the version being used with the following code:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

The output from this is as follows:

> 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

If anyone could steer me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read and help.

Comment: you probably have multiple versions of python installed ... and the python version you are running is not the python version that python_setuptools is tied to ...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Python 2.7 is the only version installed and the only version running. Please see the edit in my question. Thanks again

Comment: thousands of people use bs4(maybe hundreds of thousands) and all they do is `pip install bs4` ... if that is not working for you then perhaps your installation is broken.  it might be easier for you to use a python distribution like anaconda that is aimed at windows and has a built in visual package manager ...

Comment: I have used pip to install other packages without any issues. This is the only one that won't work. That's the reason why I decided to come here and ask the question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue. What I did is to first uninstall the bs4 package from the pip window when you open the python environments in visual studio. Then reinstall that package again. This works for me.